# Role of [784, 20] when defining random variable

Tags: tensorflow

What is role of [784, 200] during defining random variables ?

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 200], stddev=0.35),name="weights")
```

Comment: The title of a question should be a (short) question and not just a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

[784,200] is the shape of the variable. In the tutorial example, the `weight` is used to multiply the 784-dimensional image vectors to produce 200-dimensional vector.